# How can I make a GameObject point towards another GameObject in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried this code but it doesn't work correctly.
Edit: LookAt makes the GameObject invisible

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyPoint : MonoBehaviour {

    public float offset;
    public Transform target;

    private void Update()
    {
        Vector2 difference = target.position - transform.position;
        float rotZ = Mathf.Atan(difference.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotZ + offset);
    }
}
```

Comment: `LookAt makes the GameObject invisible` ... what do you mean? It only rotates the object ... is it possible that it becomes "invisible" due to Backface-Culling?

Comment: .@DanHasAPan what kind of object is `EnemyPoint` attached to? Also, can you edit this question and include the code you're using where `LookAt` "makes the GameObject invisible" ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html).

> Rotates the transform so the `forward` vector points at `target`'s current position.

```
transform.LookAt(target);
```

Simply place this on your objectA and in the `target` field drag&drop any other objectB → objectA's `forward` vector will always point towards `objectB`.

---

An alternative overwrite also takes a world position as `Vector3` instead so you can also use

```
transform.LookAt(target.position);
```

which will basically do exactly the same thing.

---

If you need another axis pointing towards the target you can still use `LookAt` and afterwards [`Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html). E.g. in order to not make the `forward` but rather the `up` Vector of the object point towards the target you can use

```
transform.LookAt(target);
transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * 90);
```

Comment: Wait isn't LookAt used in the camera?

Comment: @DanHasAPan Yes, `LookAt` can be used on any `Transform`. The camera does have one, but so does the GameObject that `EnemyPoint` is attached to.

Answer (score 0):

this thread is pretty old, but nonetheless i thought i might just pitch in. In line 13 you're using the wrong trig function. Using `Mathf.Atan2(y, x)` yields the arctangent y/x in the range of -π to +π, instead, you're using `Mathf.Atan(y)` which just does calculations based on **y only** and doesn't take into account the x value as well.

```
float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg //Get arctangential of x and y and turn it into degrees with 180/π
```